# Connect 4 C# (How to draw the grid)

Tags: c#, graphics

I've worked out most of the code and have several game classes. The one bit I'm stuck on at the moment, it how to draw the actual Connect 4 grid. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this `for` loop? I get no errors but the grid doesn't appear. I'm using C#.

```
private void Drawgrid() 
{
    Brush b = Brushes.Black;
    Pen p = Pens.Black;
    for (int xCoor = XStart, col = 0; xCoor < XStart + ColMax * DiscSpace; xCoor += DiscSpace, col++)
    {
        // x coordinate beginning; while the x coordinate is smaller than the max column size, times it by
        // the space between each disc and then add the x coord to the disc space in order to create a new circle.
        for (int yCoor = YStart, row = RowMax - 1; yCoor < YStart + RowMax * DiscScale; yCoor += DiscScale, row--)
        {
            switch (Grid.State[row, col])
            {
                case GameGrid.Gridvalues.Red:
                    b = Brushes.Red;
                    break;
                case GameGrid.Gridvalues.Yellow:
                    b = Brushes.Yellow;
                    break;
                case GameGrid.Gridvalues.None:
                    b = Brushes.Aqua;
                    break;
            }
        }
        MainDisplay.DrawEllipse(p, xCoor, yCoor, 50, 50);
        MainDisplay.FillEllipse(b, xCoor, yCoor, 50, 50);
    }
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: @John Rasch - sorry we both seem to be editing. I'll stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `Drawgrid()` needs to be executed when the window is redrawing itself.

The `Invalidate()` call tells the application that it needs to redraw the window contents (it triggers a redraw of your window). This code (with the exception of the `Invalidate()` call) should be in your overridden `OnPaint()` method, otherwise whatever gets drawn by this code will be immediately overwritten by the default drawing code in `OnPaint()` (which, by default, will probably draw a white background) when you make the `Invalidate()` call.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // (your painting code here...)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an onDraw() method.

Before this function I have this code to store the image as a bitmap:

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainBitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            MainDisplay = Graphics.FromImage(MainBitmap);
            MainDisplay.Clear(Color.Aqua);

            Drawgrid();


        }

Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Sorry that it isn't nicely spaced out in the above comment.

Comment: @Matt Wilde: That is not how you do custom drawing in Winforms.  You need to do what Scott says, inherit your board control from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and override its `OnPaint` method.  If you want to use a bitmap as some kind of buffer, that is OK (not great), but then you actually need to draw the bitmap to the control surface in the `OnPaint` method using `Graphics.DrawImage`.  Simply drawing on an in-memory bitmap does not make its content magically appear on screen.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to work out what you mean (I'm very new to C# and have just started a module in 'Software Development' at University).

I call Drawgrid() at the end of the Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e), is this not enough?

Comment: @Matt - In a windowing system, a window needs to be able to redraw its contents at various times. Rather than having a one-time method that draws on the window, the drawing code is located in a callback (typically called OnDraw or OnPaint). The Operating system will call this method whenever the window's appearance needs to be refreshed. Your code must be within such a callback - this is how you do drawing in a window. Look up **OnPaint** in C# literature.